# How do i change the way my url displays? 

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

How can I make my pages search engine friendly by showing as a directory instead of a specific file name?

ie: domain.com/about instead of doamin.com/about.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.html [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Google about 'SEO friendly urls', you will be able to find different ways of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Apache, you need to configure some rewrite rules using [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html).